# Compare all parameters excluding the one selected?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm working in SQL Server 2008. I've created a stored proc, that is passed multiple values from a temp table. Here's sample code of how the temp table is being populated:

```
DECLARE @OwnerKey varchar(75) = '2,3,7,9,14,18,23,26,28'

/* ***** Temp Table ***** */
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#OwnerTable','U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #OwnerTable
CREATE TABLE #OwnerTable (Owner varchar(10))
INSERT INTO #OwnerTable
SELECT value from TTT.ParseList(@Ownerkey,',')
/* ***** Temp Table ***** */
```

Later I joined to this table, in order to bring in the multiple owner keys as such:

```
SELECT T.Product, O.ownerid
FROM Table AS T
JOIN #OwnerTable AS O
    ON O.Owner = T.Owner
```

The issue I'm having is that this stored proc is being used in a report and I need to exclude the parameter being selected as its supposed to be compared to the other keys. This question may be convoluted, I'll do my best to answer questions.

Essentially if a user chooses parameter 2 we want to compare the results to all other keys excluding key number 2 and I need to do this in ssms. I've tried a `Merge when not matched`, to no avail. Sorry for the long question, new to sql.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to do something like this:

```
SELECT T.Product
      ,O.ownerid
FROM Table AS T
LEFT JOIN #OwnerTable AS O
    ON O.Owner = T.Owner
WHERE O.ownerid IS NULL;
```

In this way you "exclude" the records that match.